# UVs appearing outside texture while some are still inside

Tags: edit-mode, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

UVs appearing outside texture while some are still inside

The ones on the inside are fine. I could move those UVs over to the texture area by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> and moving them over, but it will not be accurate.

I was trying to bake the texture but it seemed that all of the other UVs were outside. Is there a way to have them back inside in the correct place?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what's your problem, you can select the UVs that are outside and put them inside, plus if they are outside but the image is set to repeat, it's as if the UVs were inside